# Libgdx networking for board game

Tags: java, android, network-programming, libgdx

I'm writing a turn-based card game and I want to make it multiplayer.
I am a beginner on networking but after reading some articles, I decided I have to use TCP for my type of game. Furthermore, I don't know how to make a host-join lobby to play the game.
Should I use only libGDX networking classes, or use any other third-party library?
If so, which should I use?

Comment: Since you put android in the tags,  what about Google play? They have free realise support for your game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of choices but I would say you should use Kryonet as your networking library.
[Kryonet](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryonet)

Kryonet uses Kryo serializer to serialize your data and then send it over the newtwork. It uses Non Blocking IO in its networking implementation. I have used it and liked it.

You can also use Netty which is a very high level networking library but will be a bit tough to begin with.
[Netty](http://netty.io/)

You can write your own protocols in Netty.

And if you want to learn networking from Core I will advise you to use plain java sockets as that will make you better at the particular topic and then you will understand high level libraries much better.

Comment: What type of server should i use to host my lightweight game?

Comment: @nrallakis4 what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Could i use a simple web server for sites?

Comment: I am really not sure about what you are asking.

Comment: My bad, nvm, I have the server program that waits for clients to connect.. This is going to run on a server... From where should i rent my server? Could i use for example hostgator? Do i have to pay a lot? Sorry if I sound silly.

Comment: You need to get a VPS for hosting server. There are many websites where you can get VPS from.

Comment: Thank you very much, and sorry for my noobness